# Как написать регулярное выражение c тире '-' для url Django?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, django, django-urls

Мой проект представляет каталог. Как сделать красивый URL при обработке запроса, чтобы значения одного параметра, выбранные пользователем в качестве фильтра, в данном случае "brand", писались через тире?

Вот так:

> https://shop.ru/catalog/?brand=1stplayer-aerocool-akasa-asus

В моём случае после выбора нескольких фильтров получается уродливая строка запроса в виде:

> http://shop.ru/catalog/?brand=1stplayer&brand=aerocool&brand=akasa&brand=asus

Как написать файл urls.py чтобы всё выводилось красиво?

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, re_path
from catalog.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'catalog/(?P<q>)(?P<price>)(?P<brand>)', catalog),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django import http
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from catalog.models import Corpus
from catalog import forms


# Create your views here.


def catalog(request, q, price, brand) -> HttpResponse:
    objects = Corpus.objects.all()
    search_value = ""
    pr = ""
    if request.method == "GET":
        if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
            q = request.GET['q']
            search_value = q
            objects = objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
        if 'price' in request.GET and request.GET['price']:
            pr = request.GET['price']
            pricerange = pr.split('-')
            objects = objects.filter(price__gte=pricerange[0], price__lte=pricerange[1])

    return render(request, 'catalog.html', {'corpuses': objects,
                                            'search_value': search_value,
                                            'priceform': forms.PriceForm({'price': pr}),
                                            'brandform': forms.BrandForm
                                            })
```

Код views ещё не дописал, так как надо разобраться с url-строкой.
Моя форма(для ясности):
[image: форма для отправки]

Comment: а как вариант просто фильтрацию с помощью ajax? и не надо будет никаких страшных url

Comment: `r'catalog/(?P<q>)(?P<price>)(?P<brand>)'` найдёт только `catalog/`. Почему вы добавили "пустые" подмаски после `catalog/`?

Comment: Шаблон именованных групп составляется так `(?P<имя>шаблон)`

Comment: Не знаю что такое ajax. После catalog/ добавил пустые подмаски от бессилия и отсутствия информации. Они не меняют функционала, так как к ним не прикреплены regexp

Comment: в примерах же все достаточно наглядно https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: Не совсем понимаю её на английском